# TCP IP Communication using C++

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio

Im trying to make a TCP/IP client using boost::asio in C++. I have created function that creates a socket to connect to the server

```
    void TCP_IP_Communication::Create_Socket()

    {
     ...
   _socket = new tcp::socket(_io); //create socket

  _io.run();

 boost::system::error_code error= boost::asio::error::host_not_found;


try
{
while (error && endpoint_iterator != end) //if error go to next endpoint
    {
      _socket->close();
      _socket->connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
    }
 //if error throw error

if(error)
    throw boost::system::system_error(error);

//else the router is connected
boost::asio::read_until(*_socket,buf,'\n');

}}
```

Then I use another function/thread to send a command and receive response.

```
try
{
    if(p=='i')

             _socket->send(boost::asio::buffer(" sspi l1\n\n")); //sending signal presence for input command

        else

        _socket->send(boost::asio::buffer(" sspo l1\n\n")); //sending signal presence for output command



    for(; ;)  //loop reading all values from router
  {

    //wait for reply??


        boost::asio::read_until(*_socket,buf,'\n');

        std::istream is(&buf);
        std::getline(is,this->data);
        std::cout<<std::endl<<this->data;
```

The problem is, each time I connect to the server it gives a response

```
? "login"
```

But I need to suppress it when I send a command. Actually it shouldn't show up as I'm not connecting to the server each time I send a command,but it does. What did I do wrong here? I just cant figure it out.

The main function is like this:

```
int main()
{

TCP_IP_Connection router;
    router.Create_Socket();
    boost::thread router_thread1,router_thread2;
    router_thread1=boost::thread(&TCP_IP_Connection::get_status,&router,'i'); 
    router_thread1.join();
    std::string reply="\nend of main()";
    std::cout<<reply;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Beware that the `run` method of `io_service` does _not_ return until explicitly stopped.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you mean the function that creates socket in my code needs to be stopped using return() or something, else it wont stop? (bit confused!!)

Comment: The code after `_io.run()` will not execute, as the `run` function will loop until [`io_service::stop`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html) is called.

Comment: But io.run() does not seem to be the problem..

Comment: If you don't use async.opearations - do not call `_io.run()`. As far as I see, your `io_` doesn't have any work anyway, so `run` would return immediately. But the subsequent *sync* operations won't work correctly with this `io_`.